# moduleNotFoundError: no module named (*)

Tags: python, pytest, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to run my tests using `python -m pytest` but I get an error that
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'`
When using `nosetests` or anything else it works fine, but when trying to use pytest, it doesn't work.
My tree looks like below, do you have any advice why it doesn't work?

```
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── data
│   └── data_file
├── exported_register.csv
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── sample
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   ├── dziennik.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   ├── przedmiot.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   ├── simple.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   └── uczen.cpython-39.pyc
│       ├── dziennik.py
│       ├── package_data.dat
│       ├── przedmiot.py
│       ├── simple.py
│       └── uczen.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── test_ASSERTPY_uczen.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.1.pyc
│   │   ├── test_ASSERTPY_uczen.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.5.pyc
│   │   ├── test_ASSERTPY_uczen.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── test_PYHAMCREST_uczen.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.1.pyc
│   │   ├── test_PYHAMCREST_uczen.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.5.pyc
│   │   ├── test_PYHAMCREST_uczen.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── test_UNITTEST_register.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.1.pyc
│   │   ├── test_UNITTEST_register.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.5.pyc
│   │   ├── test_UNITTEST_register.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── test_UNITTEST_uczen.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.1.pyc
│   │   ├── test_UNITTEST_uczen.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.5.pyc
│   │   ├── test_UNITTEST_uczen.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── test_simple.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.1.pyc
│   │   ├── test_simple.cpython-39-pytest-6.2.5.pyc
│   │   └── test_simple.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── test_ASSERTPY_uczen.py
│   ├── test_PYHAMCREST_uczen.py
│   ├── test_UNITTEST_register.py
│   ├── test_UNITTEST_uczen.py
│   └── test_simple.py
└── tox.ini
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run pytest with `python -m pytest` it uses the current directory as it its working dir, which doesn't contain the `sample` module (located inside ./src). The way I deal with this is I have a `conftest.py` inside my tests directory where I add my source dir to python path something like this:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

source_path = Path(__file__).parents[1].joinpath("src").resolve()
sys.path.append(str(source_path))
```

Answer (score -3):

I've recently started using pytorch and have had similar problems. Couple steps come to mind:

1. How are you writing the .py file that contains the tests? It may simply be that you need to change up how you import `sample` within the unit test file. I would expect that you need something like `import src.sample.simple`. In other words, could be just a pathing issue.
2. Try a (much) simpler folder structure and try again. If that doesn't work, try to just copy an example of a simple scheme that someone has posted. That is, just get `python -m pytest` to run somehow, then start slowly adding the complexities of your project.