# How to avoid using sys.append.path in existing project layout?

Tags: python, pytest

I inherited an existing project with a layout that looks similar to this:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── greetings.py
├── tests
│   └── test-greetings.py
```

The other two files are:

```
# greetings.py

def hello():
    return 'hello'
```

```
# test-greetings.py

import pytest
import sys 

sys.path.append('../src')
from greetings import hello


def test_hello():
    assert hello() == 'hello'
```

This works, i.e. I can run  `pytest test-greetings.py` from the tests directory but I would like to avoid using the `sys.path.append('../src')` line. Is there another way to achieve this without changing the project layout?

Comment: You could add a `conftest.py` file to your testing directory to avoid adding to path in each testing module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172229/14536215

Comment: @Tzane thanks, this could be a preferred solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that `test-greetings.py` should assume that it is run in an environment where `greetings` can be found. How to achieve that is up to whatever installs the package or runs `pytest`. A simple solution is

```
PYTHONPATH=../src pytest test-greetings.py
```

or

```
PYTHONPATH=src pytest test/test-greetings.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. This works too. But I was wandering whether something like this  `from src.greetings import hello` could be used in this layout..

Comment: No. The problem is that you either need `src` to be seen as a directory where top-level modules can be found, or (if you wrote `from src.greetings import hello`) that `src` is seen as a top-level package (which again requires an appropriate search path). Either way, the solution is outside the scope of the code itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just for my understanding. Are you saying that in a scenario where the `tests` directory would be placed inside `src` directory than the `from src.greetings import hello` would work?

Comment: If `src` could be found in a directory listed in the search path, yes, `from src.greetings import hello` would work, because `greetings` is a module in the package `src`.