# Python Receive ModuleNotFound Error and Cannot Perform Integration Tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Repo: https://github.com/ckvj/crypto-analysis

I am creating a package called `cryptotax` and following conventional structure of Root Repo > SRC > Package, with tests in a `Tests` folder under Root Repo.

I can run package as expected and receive expected output (though technically need to be in SRC to run, it won't work from other directories).

But when I run pytest I receive `ModuleNotFound` error message. [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JUmE.jpg)

I can update imports in `test_integration.py` from `cryptotax.[module]` to eg `src.cryptotax.[module]` but then I have import errors downstream in the other modules (eg trades.py, config.py, etc) and if I update them for testing then they don't work when running the package.

Was looking at other packages and they seem to not have this issue. Is it a PATH related issue, or something else I need to modify? How can I update my integration tests to run successfully?  Note previously I didn't have a src directory and things worked as expected (three passing tests). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't take pictures of text, but instead, copy them into the post itself. Most packages use this folder structure to distribute to make it clearer to users which parts is functional code, but they won't test with this exact folder structure because that's not how python works. If you put your package inside another folder, then python can no longer see that package. Put your packages in the same directory as your entry point and you should be fine.

Comment: I believe the import statement needs to be updated as you are running the `pytest` module in `test` folder so the working directory is updated. 

And When you have ran your main code, at that time the working directory is `src` hence import - `from src.cryptotax import Trades`. 

To prevent downstream error, you can change the imports statements to `src.cryptotax`.

Another, way is you can change your IDE's`Project Structure`.

Comment: Thanks @pravashpanigrahi - if I change future downstream errors then I will need to change folders from which I call the package correct? I just feel there's a better way I'm missing. wdyt?

Comment: `cryptotax` is not in the path so any import in modules within `src/cryptotax` will fail.  One way to fix this is with a `conftest.py` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172229/14536215