# pytest does not see the core folder

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I'm trying to create a test at `pytest`.

The test I'm doing is this one:

```
def test_read_main_endpoint(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json()["status_code"] == "200"
    assert response.json()["detail"] == "ok"
    assert response.json()["result"] == "working"
```

`conftest` file is this one:

```
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def client():
    return TestClient(app=app)
```

The problem is that it doesn't find the file.

```
tests/conftest.py:3: in <module>
    from app.main import app
app/main.py:3: in <module>
    from core.config import settings
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

The file where it's trying to get is in the folder of the `app/core` not the folder of the test:

```
- app/
  |- __init__.py
  |- main.py
  |- core/
     |- __init__.py
     |- config.py
- tests/
  |- __init__.py
  |- conftest.py
  |- test_main.py
```

`main` file is this one:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from core.config import settings


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {
        "status_code": "200",
        "detail": "ok",
        "result": "working",
        }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host=settings.host,
                port=settings.port, reload=True)
```

`conf` file is this one:

```
import os
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file='.env')
    host: str = Field('127.0.0.1', env='HOST')
    port: int = Field('8008', env='PORT')
    base_dir: str = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


settings = Settings()
```

Why doesn't the `pytest` get files from the folder?

Comment: One way is to modify your python path in you `tests/conftest.py` script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172116/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named/70172229#70172229

Comment: change the core.config to app.core.config. See if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `core.config` to `app.core.config`.

the pythonpath should be configure to parent folder of app and tests and once you run it from the tests you need to specify the full namespace of the module

Comment: If I change `core.config` to `app.core.config`.  Pytest works but app dont work when I try to run the `python app/main.py` application.


`from app.core.config import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: how do you run the app ? do u know if the PYTHONPATH sets to the parent folder of app ?