# '__init__.py' file in tests folder

Tags: python, pytest

I am having problems with pytest my directory looks like below:

```
├── modules
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data
|   |   ├── __init__.py
│   |   └── tables.py
├── tests
│   └── test_tabels.py
└──  main.py
```

My problem was that I was getting a `Pytest Discovery Error`. When reading the error output I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named modules`. In my `test_tables.py` file I obviously need to import classes and definitions to test them, so I would for instance run `from modules.data import GetData`.

By adding a `__init__.py` file to the `tests` folder I am not getting the error anymore and can run my tests. However, I do not understand why this works. I have other repos where I do not have an `__init__.py` file in the `tests` folder where I do not have the issue. This makes me wonder if I have actually solved the problem and if it makes sense to add the `__init__.py` file.

UPDATE:

I have, prior to writing the question, read explanations about the `__init__.py` file from other posts and understand the purpose. My question is more focused on why adding a `__init__.py` solves my problem, I am not importing code from the `tests` folder anywhere, it is only used for unit testing.

Also I can run the tests in the CLI but I cannot use the debugger or see the test in VS codes *Testing* tab. When opening the tab I see the message `Pytest Discovery Error`.

Comment: Can you try running `pytest --collect-only` and post any error you get?

Comment: Make sure to use `python -m pytest tests` when you run your tests, using the `-m` flag is important so your project root is added to the path. https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: @alec_djinn I do not get any errors when running the command.

Comment: @Tzane when using the command it works fine. But I am using the debugger in VS code and with the error I cannot debug my tests or even se the tests in the "Testing" tab.

Comment: @Sam sadly not really. I understand the purpose of `__init__.py`, but I do not understand why it solve my problem. Accordingly to the post I would not need a `__init__.py` file as I do not import the code in the `tests` folder anywhere, it is only used for testing.

Comment: Have you tried modifying your path for tests with a `conftest.py`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172229/14536215

Comment: @andKaae you should add the `VS code` tag to your question. This is not really a Pyhon/Pytest problem, it is limited to VS code.