# Importing python files from a different directory with dependencies

Tags: python, pytest

So my folder structure looks like this

```
Project_root/
├── src/
│   └── module/
│       ├── main.py
│       └── variable.py
└── tests/
    └── module/
        └── test_main.py
```

With these simple files

##### variable.py

```
c = 1
```

##### main.py

```
from variable import c

def add(a, b):
    return a + b + c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(add(1, 2))
```

##### test_main.py

```
import sys, os 
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from src.module.main import add

def test_add():
    """Test the add function."""
    assert add(1, 2) == 5
    assert add(-1, 1) == 2
    assert add(0, 0) == 2

test_add()
```

Running test_main.py does not work however as it yields the following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'variable'

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Have you placed `__init__.py` files in your packages?

Comment: Tried to place it in all my directories but it did not make a difference.

Comment: You need to add `module` to your python path when testing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172116/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named/70172229#70172229

Comment: Also, if you want to run individual tests, [pytest has a couple of way to do that](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html) or if you are using an IDE like VS Code you might want to use the [test runner](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_configure-tests)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to do the following

Create a `__init__.py` file in the `src`  and `tests`  directories

Your project structure should be something like this:

```
Project_root/
├── src/
│   ├── module/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   └── variable.py
└── tests/
    ├── module/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_main.py
```

In `main.py` and `test_main.py` files, use explicit relative imports to import the module variable by using a `dot (.)`

[image]

Now, when you run `test_main.py`, it should be able to import the variable module and execute your tests (you might get assertion error for now)

```
python tests\module\test_main.py
```

Hope this helps and Let me know!!

Comment: That makes it possible to run test_main.py 
However, it is no longer to possible to run main.py as it give this error

>ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Yes, That's the way for the making this folder structure a little complex. There are workarounds to run [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: The problem is that I still want to run the main.py file. So what is the good practise solution? 

I guess I could do something like this in my main.py file

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    from variable import c
else:
    from .variable import c`

But that is maybe not recommended? Looks quite ugly...

Is it easier to keep the test files in the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

to enhance the flavor of the above answer and reduce current possible errors regarding `relative imports`...

stick with the convention of adding `__init__.py` in `src/` which basically treats python project's `src/` directory as `package` and subdirs as `subpackages`. This structure allows you to use `relative imports` within the module subpackage

This is a modular approach that is beneficial for larger projects **(incase you want to extend your existing project to a larger project.)**