Python Error: Module not found even with module import
I have an issue related a module imports.
For example, I have the following file structure:
main_folder -> src -> main.py and logic.py
main_folder -> test -> tests_logic.py
The tests is for pytest file, I'm importing the other 2 files to the test, using for example:
from main_file.src.main import something
from main_file.src.logic import something
The issue is that every time I run the test file, the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named appears, even with the right imports for the modules in the test file.
How can I solve this?
I tried to refactor the repo, setup environment. The only thing that works is if I put all the .py files in the same directory, without subfolders.

When you run the tests, src is not in the path so you get import errors. Easiest way imo to fix this is to add src to the path with a conftest.py: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172229/14536215


for main_folder and src, make sure they have an __init__.py file (an empty file is sufficient)
make sure that the parent directory of main_folder is included in sys.path before the import statement is executed. For example:

import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/parent')

from main_file.src.main import something
from main_file.src.logic import something

Note that there are more ways to configure sys.path. The example I gave might not be the most appropriate for your usecase.
